# Typedeffing a function pointer seems to be local to just one header file

Tags: c, struct, include, header-files

I'm trying to write a webserver in C, and I have a header file called `route.h`. Inside `route.h` I have the line `typedef void (*RouteHandler)(struct HTTPRequest *, struct HTTPResponse *);` which I believe creates the typedef `RouteHandler` which is a function that returns nothing, and takes two pointers to structs as arguments. Also inside `route.h` is this struct:

```
struct RouteTableEntry {
    enum HTTPMethod method;
    char *route;
    RouteHandler handler;
};
```

This code compiles just fine, however when I try and use the typedef in a different header, `server.h`, I get the compiler error: `server.h:27:8: error: unknown type name ‘RouteHandler’`.

Here is my code:

`route.h`

```
#ifndef ROUTE_H_GUARD_
#define ROUTE_H_GUARD_

#include <stdlib.h>

#include "http.h"
#include "server.h"

typedef void (*RouteHandler)(struct HTTPRequest *, struct HTTPResponse *);

struct RouteTableEntry {
    enum HTTPMethod method;
    char *route;
    RouteHandler handler;
};

...

#endif
```

`server.h`

```
#ifndef SERVER_H_GUARD_
#define SERVER_H_GUARD_

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "http.h"
#include "route.h"

...

extern RouteHandler get_handler(enum HTTPMethod method, char *route, RouteHandler handler);

...

#endif
```

(I've reduced the code to just the relevant parts - if the full thing is necessary I will post the rest)

Comment: Nitpick: you are defining `RouteHandler` not as a function type but as a *pointer to* function type.

Comment: @JohnBollinger what is the advantage of using a function pointer? Or does it only work that way?

Comment: It is possible to typedef a function type, but (i) that's not what you have done, and (ii) it's not very useful to do so.  *Function pointer* types are object types.  You can declare them as the types of variables, function parameters, function return types, structure members, *etc*.  As far as I am aware, on the other hand, the only thing you can do with *function* type typedefs is use them to prototype functions, and that usage is non-idiomatic and obfuscatory.

Comment: Ohhh sorry, misread your comment. Thanks for the help anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `route.h` itself includes `server.h`, and this before the beginning of the scope of the typedef.  It is while processing *that* inclusion of `server.h` that the compiler complains, rightly, that there is no declaration of type `RouteHandler` in scope.

If indeed `route.h` and `server.h` each require something that the other declares then it is time to refactor.  You haven't provided enough details for us to offer specific suggestions, but the kind of circular dependency you presently have will cause you continuing grief.

On the other hand, if `route.h` actually doesn't need anything from `server.h` then it ought not to be including it.

Comment: Ahhh thanks, figured it would probably be something to do with circular dependency.